# How to redirect a k8s "exit code 137"?

Tags: bash, redirect, kubernetes

I'm killing a process inside a pod with command:

```
kubectl  exec ${pod} -- bash -c "kill -9 \`ps -ef | grep ${something} | grep -v grep | awk '{print \$2}'\` >/dev/null 2>&1" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

and I get `"command terminated with exit code 137"` message that indicates that process `${something}` was really killed. How can I redirect the exit code?

Comment: Redirect? You can access exit code of last command using `$?` variable

Comment: I don't need the status code, I just want to run the kill specific proc on specific pod in a script without recieving the k8s exit code on the screen

Comment: I may be wrong, but try to write `&>/dev/null` instead of `/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Found it...I needed to add redirect specificly to the kubectl

Answer (score 1):

Running the Process:

```
kubectl --namespace=magellan exec $pod 2>/dev/null -- bash -c "some remote command"
```

And after it killing the process does not redirect the error to screen